# PixiJS - Not all touchend events triggering (outside of displayObject)

Tags: pixi.js

Pixijs (3.0.8) supports multi-touch as shown in their demos, and I've set up `start`, `move` and `end` listeners for touches on my mobile device.

The touches are registered on a square within the canvas which I'll call the `interactiveArea`, but the touchend events trigger when let go outside of the area as well. This is behavior that works fine with a single mouse cursor.

However, when using more fingers, having touches with the identifiers `0`,`1` and `2`, only the first touchEnd is triggered outside of the area.
So I press and hold 3 fingers inside the `interactiveArea` and move them all outside of it. Then I let go of `1`, and then the others. I won't be notified of touchEnds for event 0 and 2, and I'd have to re-register 3 touches and let go properly just to get a touchend for `2` triggered!

Any tips on how I can detect all touchends, rather than have it stop on the first touchend? I've tried working with a setTimeout hack as well, but that really doesn't suit my use case.

**Edit** I've made a basic codepen to demonstrate how `touchendoutside` is only triggered once. https://codepen.io/Thomaswithaar/pen/EygRjM Do visit the pen on mobile, as it is about touches rather than mouse interactivity.
Holding two fingers on the red square and then moving them out and letting go will only trigger *one* `touchendoutside` event.

Comment: It sounds like your not holding reference to each touchpoint properly. Please show your code or we can't help you.

Comment: @Karmacon I've added a codepen that console.logs the touchevents on the red square, and edited my post. I'd like to hear your feedback and see if there's a way to get all `touchendoutside` events to trigger properly.

Comment: This is indeed a PIXI bug. I'm going to make a pull request and then provide you with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the PIXI source code, there is indeed a bug in the Interaction Manager. Here is the method that processes touch end events:

```
InteractionManager.prototype.processTouchEnd = function ( displayObject, hit )
{
    if(hit)
    {
        this.dispatchEvent( displayObject, 'touchend', this.eventData );

        if( displayObject._touchDown )
        {
            displayObject._touchDown = false;
            this.dispatchEvent( displayObject, 'tap', this.eventData );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if( displayObject._touchDown )
        {
            displayObject._touchDown = false;
            this.dispatchEvent( displayObject, 'touchendoutside', this.eventData );
        }
    }
};
```

You can see in the else statement that a `touchendoutside` event gets dispatched when `displayObject._touchDown` is true. But after you release your first finger, it sets the flag to false. That is why you only receive that event once.

I've opened an issue here:
https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/2662

And provided a fix here:
https://github.com/karmacon/pixi.js/blob/master/src/interaction/InteractionManager.js
This solution removes the flag and uses a counter instead. I haven't tested it yet, so please let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to implement the workaround when I get to it, and I'll follow the github issue closely. I'll likely vote this as the accepted answer soon.